# How to truncate a SHA256 key to emulate a 128 key in Ruby

Tags: python, ruby, sha256, hashlib

I want to truncate a 256 key to simulate a 128 key. This is easy enough in Python with `[:16]`

```
>>> hashed_master_key = hashlib.sha256(master_key).digest()
>>> len(hashed_master_key)
32
>>> hashed_master_key = hashlib.sha256(master_key).digest()[:16]
>>> len(hashed_master_key)
16
```

How can we do the same using Ruby?

```
2.2.1 :028 > hashed_master_key = Digest::SHA256.digest master_key
 =>     "\x94DS\xF2:;\x8FU\x9C:v\xB6\xD4\x1C\xB4\xD0\x88/D\xA3\xF0\x91\xBC\x19\x14\x98\xE9\nS^.4" 
2.2.1 :029 > hashed_master_key.length
 => 32
```

Answer (score 3):

The hashing is not relevant here. Both libraries output the digest as a simple string. So in Python `[:16]` just takes the first 16 characters

The Ruby equivalent is just as simple:

```
hashed_master_key = Digest::SHA256.digest( master_key )[0,16]
```

More Ruby `String` methods are documented at http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/String.html

---

NB in Ruby you can often omit the method parameter brackets `( )` and this is a popular style of writing Ruby you will see in documentation and examples. However, that can get in the way of method chaining as used here. If you see Ruby example method calls without brackets, and you'd like to add more to a single line of code, you can feel free to add the brackets back to allow it.